# Functions used to connect Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, loadrunner

We are trying to connect oracle db from loadrunner. Could you please help us in providing these details. we wanted the script to get the data from oracle DB before starting the execution. In our testing we are used different application and protocols used Web http/html, Tuxedo and CRM aplls.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, connect to the db during run to get parameters? Connect to the DB as part of the business process? Connect before the test or during the test?

Answer (score 0):

You are headed down a path which will cause you harm.   Build your data files ahead of time and include them with the scripts.   I could tell you how to solve your problem technically, but doing so would the the technical equivalent of instructing you how to use a gun to rob a bank, ultimately a bad set of advice.  Your question also exposes a lack of critical skills in client side architecture and communications.  This gap will not serve you well as a performance tester.